# ASP.NET entity data model get list with relitionships

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-relationship

I have "Question" and "QuestionTypes". In "Question" table there is a foreign key that refrence the other table. I want to show question attributes with type name.

Repeater code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <%#Eval("QuestionSubject")%>
        </td>
        <td>
             <%#Eval("Question")%>
        </td>
        <td>
             <%#Eval("QuestionTypeName")%> //I want to get question typename
        </td>                          //TypeName is in other table
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And here is code behind:

```
private IEnumerable<TableSurveyQuestion> Questions()
{
    int survey_id = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["survey_id"]);
    IEnumerable<TableSurveyQuestion> questions= db.TableSurveyQuestions.Where(a => a.SurveyId == survey_id);
    return questions;
}
```

I bind this founction to repeater data source.

I tried `select new TableQuestions {typeName=x.TableQuestionTypes.TypeName}` but this did not work.

In mvc I get it like this `question.TableQuestionType.TypeName`. How do this in ASP.NET web forms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it

```
var sorular = from soru in db.TableSurveyQuestions
                  where soru.SurveyId == anket_id
                  orderby soru.QueueNo, soru.Subject ascending
                  select new
                  {
                      soru.TypeId,
                      soru.Subject,
                      soru.QuestionId,
                      soru.SurveyId,
                      soru.QueueNo,
                      SurveyTitle = soru.TableSurvey.Title,
                      TypeName = soru.TableSurveyQuestionType.TypeName,
                      SoruSayisi = db.TableSurveyQuestions.Where(a => a.SurveyId == anket_id).Count(),

                      Secenekler = from secenekler in soru.TableSurveyOptions
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       OptionId = secenekler.OptionId,
                                       OptionName = secenekler.OptionName,
                                       QuestionId = secenekler.QuestionId,
                                       VoteCount = secenekler.TableSurveyVotes.Count
                                   }
                  };
```

thanks.